# How to change the Animation settings of a device in Android - Java?

Tags: java, android, animation

I have recently seen about a feature `Remove Animations` in my Android 10 device. So, how can we toggle that setting programmatically in `java`. This is what i am talking about

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we cant. We can only modify the settings related to the app and not the device. Specially we cant make changes in the `Accessibility` section.